# How to use partialmethod with Django Jinja2

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am following [this](https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/django-hack-help-text-modal-instance/) guide to generate a method similar to `get_FOO_display()` to display the `help_text` for a named field in a template (which I define as `get_FOO_help_text()`):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Call the superclass first; it'll create all of the field objects.
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Again, iterate over all of our field objects.
        for field in self._meta.fields:

            # Create a string, get_FIELDNAME_help_text
            method_name = "get_{0}_help_text".format(field.name)

            # We can use partialmethod to create the method with a pre-defined argument
            partial_method = partialmethod(
                self._get_FIELD_help_text, field=field.name
            )

            # And we add this method to the instance of the class.
            setattr(self, method_name, partial_method)

    def _get_FIELD_help_text(self, field):
        value = getattr(self, field.help_text)
        return str(value)
```

However, when I use the Jinja2 template engine to render the template using `{{ object.get_FOO_help_text() }}` I get the following error:

> TypeError at /display/ 'partialmethod' object is not
>   callable

It needs to be callable in the template as otherwise Jinja displays:

`functools.partialmethod(<bound method MyModel._get_FIELD_help_text of <object: instance>>, , field_name='FOO')`

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have field FOO in your model ?

Comment: @iklinac yes, unfortunately that's not the cause